# C# 4.0 grammar: How do you properly define an interface method?

Tags: c#, grammar

According to the official language specification of C# 4.0 an interface method declaration is defined as:

`interface-method-declaration:
attributes? new? return-type identifier 
type-parameter-list ( formal-parameter-list? ) type-parameter-constraints-clauses? ;`

where

`type-parameter-list: < type-parameters >`

So my question is: does the `type-parameter-list` must always follow the interface method name or it can be skipped? The specification says that it should always follow the name but this seems little strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the formal grammar in the specification, interface methods must be generic.

Obviously this is a mistake, the type-parameter-list is supposed to be optional as in all the other method-declaration productions. Specifications can have bugs, too :)

Unfortunately, the real specification for C# is "whatever csc.exe does" - and there are hundreds of significant differences to the documented behavior once you start looking close enough.